# Avoid mutating property BUG, Vue + Nuxt + Property Decorators

Tags: typescript, vue.js, nuxt.js

This is seriously driving me insane. I am not mutating a prop. I know what that is and why you should get that error, and I am not doing it. Can someone please help me because I cannot get rid of this error.

This is my component:

```
<template>
  <h2>
    {{ title }}
  </h2>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue, Prop } from 'nuxt-property-decorator'

@Component({})
export default class Navbar extends Vue {
  @Prop() title!: string
}
</script>
```

I call on it like this:

```
<TopHeader title="Generera rapport"/>
```

And i constantly get this error:

```
[Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "title"

found in

---> <Navbar> at components/TopHeader.vue
```

This is obviously some kind of bug, I have the latest versions of `nuxt`, `nuxt-property-decorator` and `vue` (before vue 3). Have someone encountered this and can you please help me?

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "nuxt-buefy": "^0.4.21",
    "nuxt-property-decorator": "^2.9.1",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
```

Comment: You are updating the prop at some point (somewhere). More code would be needed here.

Comment: First thing I see is that you didn't specified the *runtime* type of the prop: `@Prop({ type: String })`. I don't think this is the problem though.

Comment: Also, your component is a class classed `Navbar` but you show use `<TopHeader>` usage, are you sure this is the same component?

Comment: Thank you all for comments. None of those above was related to the problem. I had to delete my package-lock file and reinstall every package manually, checking each time for version mismatches and finally the error is now gone. The code is the same. It was due to some node packages mismatches. I want 6 hours of my life back...

Answer (score 3):

This is due to typescript compiler generated code, it is injecting an assigment into the generated class constructor.
You can confirm this by looking at the generated code in your browser's javascript debugger.

This compiler option may help: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier

Note that on a fresh vue project (created with @vue/cli) this creates a setup that does not produce the symptom.

Comment: I feel like what [OP found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72083415/avoid-mutating-property-bug-vue-nuxt-property-decorators/72087406#comment127371726_72083415) is somehow fixing the issue but I'm not sure that it's a long term solution. We now have a reference to the compiler option.